# Show hidden fieldset in Sencha

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I've set a fielset to hidden.

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
order: 'none',
hidden: true,
hideMode: 'visibility',
id: 'fieldSetAddContact',
margin: '-20 50 0 50',
maxHeight: 110,
maxWidth: 800,
minHeight: 110,
minWidth: 800,
padding: 10,
title: '',
layout: {
type: 'vbox',
align: 'stretch'
}
```

I like to set it visible with this code

```
var addContact = Ext.get('fieldSetAddContact');
addContact.setVisible(true);
```

This does not work. If I set the layout type to something else like fit, the fieldset will be displayed, but in the top left corner of the parent element and not at the place it is displaed if I set the element as visaible in the settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext-method-get) Ext.get() method doesn't retrieve Components! So I suggest to use Ext.getCmp() method - [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp).
I tried it on fiddle and the fieldset is displayed